# UEFI not showing boot entries

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-11, uefi, dualboot

Basically, the `Windows Boot Manager` entry does not show up neither on my boot menu, or on my boot priorities.

I have encryption on my Windows (BitLocker)

On the boot menu, it's only showing all my drives, not the actual boot entries.

UEFI info: `H110M-K BIOS Ver. 4211` Asus UEFI.

I have Windows 11 installed.

Note that I have a Ventoy USB drive with some ISOs in it, I got windows live OSs, Linux live OSs, so if I need them to fix it, I have them and I can boot into them.

Couldn't upload pics so I'm just typing all of it into here:

- Fast Boot:Enabled.
- Next Boot after AC Power Loss: Normal Boot.
- Launch CSM:Enabled,
- Boot Device Control: UEFI and Legacy OPROM,
- Boot from Network Devices: Legacy only, * * Boot From Storage Devices: UEFI driver first,
- Boot from PCI-E Expansion Devices:Legacy only.
- Secure boot state: Enabled.
- PK state: Unloaded.
- OS type: Other OS.

If you need me to install Linux to fix this, I can install fedora 38

Comment: Does that mean that you're unable to boot at all? If so, what was the action that caused it?

Comment: Is CSM [Legacy] Mode enabled? What are the UEFI firmware settings showing on the boot tab _(not the UEFI bootable drives page, but the actual Boot tab within the UEFI firmware settings)_

Comment: Answer to @harrymc : I tried to delete my Ubuntu's partitions to reinstall it, and I don't know if I really succeeded.

Comment: @SaltyRhino95857 It may be easier to take a photo of it and post the photo

Comment: @SaltyRhino95857 Disable CSM Mode, as it should never be enabled, and once done, the system should boot without issue _(the sole purpose of [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) was to support distros circa <2017 that didn't yet support EFI boot - Win7+ supports EFI boot, as does every distro since ~2017)_ - this goes for all the _Legacy_ options - they should all be set to UEFI only, and if an OPROM needs to be accessed in CSM Mode, it should be changed to Legacy only to access it, then once done, immediately changed back to UEFI.

Comment: You have Legacy booting enabled, i.e. the old BIOS procedure, which doesn't know anything about UEFI boot entries, it only knows how to jump to the 1st sector of any attached storage devices (master boot records).

Comment: @JW0914 @kreemoweet now the boot menu is showing `The system cannot find any bootable devices`

Comment: @SaltyRhino95857 To correct the Windows boot issue, re-enable CSM mode, boot to WinRE's /WinPE's command prompt: `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /rebuildbcd` Once booted back to the OS, convert your drives to GPT _(there's several programs that can change the partition table without re-partitioning)_. Once that's done, verify the boot partition's GUID is correct, format it as FAT32, then rebuild the boot files for EFI via: `BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Z: /f UEFI` _(where `Z:` is the mounted boot partition)_. Reboot & disable CSM Mode

Comment: @JW0914 do I need to boot from my USB drive? I can't boot into any internal drive...

Comment: Well, I guess I'll try it... You're not answering. EDIT: I tried and it wouldn't work because there's no "bootrec" command in Windows PE ISO that I made...

Comment: @SaltyRhino95857 `bootrec` is contained within every WinPE/WinRE WIM _(unless you made yours from scratch using the ADK - in that case, the correct WinPE OCs weren't added)_. Download the Windows Media Creation Tool and use it to create a bootable USB - once the Setup GUI loads, `Shift`+`F10` to access a terminal.

Comment: Output of commands:fixmbr: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. Fixboot: Access is denied. Rebuild cd: Scanning all disks for windows installations. Please wait, since this may take a while... Successfully scanned windows installations. Total identified windows installations: 0. The operation completed successfully

Comment: What should I do now? Bootrec doesn't recover my OS. And I need to recover Ubuntu too.